# Navigating between multiple Tkinter GUI frames

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I found some code online to create a tkinter GUI with multiple frames. I tried to modify the code to include a frame with navigation buttons to be displayed on each frame, rather than repeating the code each time. I keep getting error messages and cannot work out how to connect the navigation buttons to the corresponding frame. 
This is the code for the closest I have got:

```
import Tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        btns = MainButtonFrame(self,SeaofBTCapp)
        btns.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()

        btns = MainButtonFrame(self,SeaofBTCapp)
        btns.pack()

class MainButtonFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Pages = [StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo ]
        for button in Pages:
            NewButton = tk.Button(self, text=str(button),
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(button))
            NewButton.pack()

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

and the error message I got is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-13-dcc5fdbf1581>", line 103, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(button))
TypeError: unbound method show_frame() must be called with SeaofBTCapp 
instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)
```

Any help would be much appreciated in suggesting what I am doing wrong in the button commands. If I can get this working I will use it as a framework to build a bigger GUI on. Thanks!

Comment: You already have the `button1` & `button2` to navigate between different frames....why you added these `btns = MainButtonFrame(self,SeaofBTCapp)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer of `MainButtonFrame` needs a parent and a controller. The controller must be the *instance* of the main app, not the *class*. Change how you create `MainButtonFrame` to be this:

```
btns = MainButtonFrame(self,controller)
```