# Tkinter GUI frames - autoloading frame using 'after'?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frames

I've been experimenting with some code I found here which lets you navigate between multiple **tkinter** GUI frames:

[Navigating between multiple Tkinter GUI frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880859/navigating-between-multiple-tkinter-gui-frames)

And I'm trying to see if I can autoload a specific frame after a certain amount of time passes, (similar to a sleep screen / screensaver).

I've used the .after method and beginning right after `frame.tkraise()`. It calls a new class called `Autoload`, which is currently just a copy of the main App Class `SeaofBTCapp`.

It works, but the obvious problem with this is that it's popping out the frame into a new window because it's calling this again:

```
tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm a total newb, so I apologize for asking a very obvious question, but what is the best way to keep it from popping out? If I copy the code from one of the Frame classes, it tells me that `__init__` is not getting enough arguments. I have tried various (obvious) things, but having trouble wrapping my head around this because it ultimately would have to be a passive function operating in the back of the main app, without hindering other functionality (calling new frames). I'm probably just overthinking this and have missed a very simple and elegant solution. Any thoughts?

Here's the full code, thanks for help!

```
import Tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.after(2000, Autoload)  #####


class Autoload(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.after(2000, Autoload)  #####


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()



app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you hoping the autoload will do? It doesn't seem to make sense to replicate the code - can't you make a function inside SeaOfBTCapp that gets called by __init__ and by autoload?

Comment: Hi, thanks, i'm trying to work out a "sleep screen" type frame, which raises after maybe 30 seconds, without having it disrupt any functionality or restarting the code. My GUI would be functional, and 30 second count would restart after every action (button commands). The GUI would "go to sleep" if no button is pressed within 30 seconds (from the .after), but it would just be a blank black frame (black button simulating black screen), when clicked, returns to main menu. I could make a function within SeaOfBTCapp, but trying to make sure this sleep method will work globally as i expand the gui

Comment: ... meaning, i'd probably have to add a function to each of the classes (menu pages). I'm fine with that, but is that the most efficient way of executing this? Any examples would be amazingly helpful, i'm getting lost the deeper I think about this. I've googled, surprised I havent been able to find anybody trying anything quite like this. Thanks!